# What is the difference between #\ , ' and #'?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, given that "a" is simply a character, what is the difference between `#\a`, `'a` `#'a`?

My question comes from the tutorialspoint.com tutorial on Lisp. At one point the tutorial introduces:

```
; a character array with all initial elements set to a
; is a string actually
(write(make-array 10 :element-type 'character :initial-element #\a)) 
(terpri)

; a two dimensional array with initial values a
(setq myarray (make-array '(2 2) :initial-element 'a :adjustable t))
(write myarray)
(terpri)
```

With the output:

```
"aaaaaaaaaa"
#2A((A A) (A A))
```

`#'` is not included in this example but I'm including it in the question because it can be confusing as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: tutorialspoint is well referenced but it doesn't really teach lisp… I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start, `a` is not "*simply a character.*" The Lisp reader parses `#\a` as the character literal `a`, which is an object in Common Lisp. Note that `#\a` and `#\A` are different character objects.

When the Lisp reader encounters a single quote, the expression following the single quote is not evaluated. Specifically, `'a` is treated as `(quote a)`, where `quote` returns its argument unevaluated. Now, `a` is a *symbol*, so `'a` evaluates to that symbol. But the Lisp reader upcases most characters it reads by default, so `'a` really evaluates to the symbol `A`. The good news is that whether you type `a` or `A`, the Lisp reader will read `A` (unless you mess with the readtable), and both `'a` and `'A` evaluate to the symbol `A`.

When the Lisp reader encounters `#'a`, the entire expression is treated as `(function a)`, which when evaluated returns the function associated with the name `a`. But, note that it is an error to use `function`, and by extension `#'`, on an identifier that does not denote a function.

To clarify this last part a bit, consider the following REPL interaction:

```
CL-USER> (defvar a 1)
A
CL-USER> a
1
CL-USER> #'a

The function COMMON-LISP-USER::A is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

Here the variable `a` is defined and given the value `1`, but when we try to access the function denoted by `a` we get an error message because there is no such function. Continuing:

```
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION A {1002DDC303}>.
CL-USER> (defun a (x) x)
A
CL-USER> (a 'b)
B
CL-USER> a
1
CL-USER> #'a
#<FUNCTION A>
```

Now we have defined a function named `a` that simply returns its argument. You can see that when we call `a` with an argument `'b` we get the expected result: `(a 'b)` --> `b`. But, then when we evaluate `a` alone we still get `1`. Symbols in Common Lisp are objects that have, among other cells, value cells and function cells. After the above interaction, the symbol `a` now has `1` in its value cell, and it has the function we have defined in its function cell. When the symbol `a` is evaluated the value cell is accessed, but when `(function a)` or `#'a` is evaluated, the function cell is accessed. You can see above that when `#'a` is evaluated, the function we defined is returned, and the REPL prints `#<FUNCTION A>` to show this.

As an aside, I wouldn't recommend using Tutorialspoint to learn Common Lisp. Glancing over the site, right away I see this:

> LISP expressions are case-insensitive, cos 45 or COS 45 are same.

This is just wrong. And, Lisp is not written in all-caps. None of this inspires faith. Instead, find a good book. There are some recommendations on the [common-lisp](/questions/tagged/common-lisp) [tag-info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info) page.

Comment: Specifically, Common Lisp is not case-insensitive, it is typically case-smashing. I do not think it would be standards-compliant to consider `|a|` and `|A|` to be the same symbol.

Answer (score 2):

> #\

This is to introduce a character.

```lisp
CL-USER> #\a
#\a
CL-USER> (character 'a)
#\A
CL-USER> (character "a")
#\a
```

> '

This is `quote`, to quote and not evaluate things and construct object literals.

```lisp
CL-USER> a 
=> error: the variable a is unbound.

CL-USER> 'a
A

CL-USER> (inspect 'a)

The object is a SYMBOL.
0. Name: "A"
1. Package: #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
2. Value: "unbound"
3. Function: "unbound"
4. Plist: NIL
>  q

CL-USER> (equal (list 1 2) (quote (1 2))) ;; aka '(1 2)
T ;; but watch out with object literals constructed with quote, prefer constructor functions.
```

> and #'

This is sharpsign-quote to reference a function.

```lisp
CL-USER> #'a
=> error: The function COMMON-LISP-USER::A is undefined.

CL-USER> (defun a () (print "hello A"))
A
CL-USER> (a)
"hello A" 
"hello A"

CL-USER> #'a
#<FUNCTION A>

CL-USER> (function a)
#<FUNCTION A>
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that, while single-quoted expressions are treated as if wrapped by a `quote` form, and sharp-quoted expressions are treated as if wrapped by a `function` form, `#\<token>` is _not_ treated as a `character` form. For example, the sharp-backslash can be followed by a named character, e.g., `#\space`.

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you!!!! 

Answer (score 1):

One can ask Lisp to describe the data objects you've mentioned.

If we look at the expressions:

```
CL-USER 13 > (dolist (object (list '#\a ''a '#'a))
              (terpri)
              (describe object)
              (terpri))


#\a is a CHARACTER
Name      "Latin-Small-Letter-A"
Code      97


(QUOTE A) is a LIST
0      QUOTE
1      A


(FUNCTION A) is a LIST
0      FUNCTION
1      A
NIL
```

If we look at the **evaluated** expressions:

```
CL-USER 5 > (dolist (object (list #\a 'a #'a))
              (terpri)
              (describe object)
              (terpri))


#\a is a CHARACTER
Name      "Latin-Small-Letter-A"
Code      97


A is a SYMBOL
NAME          "A"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<interpreted function A 422005BD54>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 73/256 internal, 0/4 external>


#<interpreted function A 422005BD54> is a TYPE::INTERPRETED-FUNCTION
CODE      (LAMBDA (B)
           A)
```